# Quick Sort Error: stack around the variable was corrupted?

Tags: c++, quicksort, corruption

I am implementing a quick sort function for class. We have to do it the same way she taught us in class with her pseudocode, or else we dont get credit.

I am getting a *runtime error* that says "***Stack around the variable 'quickArray' was corrupted***"

I played with the debugger ,and still cannot figure out what the problem is.  Im thinking that it has something to do with my Partition() function, but Im not sure. Can anyone help? Iv posted the main(), QuickSort(), and Partition() function below.

```
int main()
{


int quickArray[10] = { 5 ,99, 32, 4, 1, 12, 15 , 8, 13, 55};
int P = quickArray[0];
int R =quickArray[9];

QuickSort(quickArray,P,R);
return 0;

}
```

..........................................................................................

```
void QuickSort(int ar2[],int P, int R)
{
int Q;

if( P < R )
{
    Q =  Partition(ar2,P,R);
    QuickSort(ar2,P,Q-1);
    QuickSort(ar2,Q+1,R);
}

}
```

...........................................................................................

```
int Partition(int ar2[],int P, int R)
{
int x = ar2[R];
int i = P-1;
int temp;

for(int j = P; j <= R-1; j++)
{
    if( ar2[j] < x  )
    {
        i = i +1;
        temp = ar2[i];
        ar2[i] = ar2[j];
        ar2[j] = temp;
    }

    temp = ar2[R];
    ar2[R] = ar2[i+1];
    ar2[i+1] = temp;
}

return (i+1);
}
```

Comment: Step through the code and the error should be obvious. Hint: Look carefully at what happens at the first line of the Quicksort function.What are P and R supposed to be? What are they in actuality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the actual elements of the array not the indexes, a quick way to have debugged this would be a `cout` at the top of `QuickSort` like so:

```
void QuickSort(int ar2[],int P, int R)
{
   std::cout << "P: " << P << " R: " << R << std::endl ;
   ...
```

and also a `cout` after the `Partition` call:

```
  Q =  Partition(ar2,P,R);

  std::cout << "QS: Q= " << Q << std::endl ;
```

the fix would be to call `QuickSort` from `main` like so:

```
 QuickSort(quickArray,0,9);
```

Spending some time with the debugger in the long term will help you spot these bugs much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about debugging the problem

Answer (score 2):

You are passing wrong indices into the QuickSort function:

```
int P = quickArray[0];
int R =quickArray[9];
```

P and R are array indices, should be 0 and 9 in this case, however, you were passing the first element and last element as index into QuickSort, 55 (quickArray[9]) is out of index bound of quickArray, so you got the error.

BTW: it is better to use descriptive variable names, P and R do not well expressed what they mean in this case. You may use left, right, and pivot to replace R, R and Q, respectively as described in the QuickSort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int P = quickArray[0];
int R = quickArray[9];

QuickSort(quickArray,P,R);
```

Should be this:

```
int arrStartIndex = 0;
int arrEndIndex   = 9;

QuickSort(quickArray, arrStartIndex , arrEndIndex);
```

As pointed out by others, your code should use more descriptive names.